# pandas between time is not working

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, twitter, timestamp

I want to filter morning tweets from a 1-month tweet dataset. The column date originally was a timestamp column therefore I converted it to date time, index, and use between time. But it returns an empty data frame. What's wrong?

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


if __name__ == "__main__":
    df = pd.read_csv('inst.csv',encoding='utf-8')
    df.date = pd.to_datetime(df.date)
    df.set_index(pd.DatetimeIndex(df.date),inplace=True)
    mor = df.between_time('6:00','12:00')
    print(mor)
```

Here's a piece of data

```
,X,Unnamed..0,id,owner_id,post_src,caption,likes,comments,date,code,location_id,location_name,location_slug,location_type,postal_code,lat,lng
4,3,3,1.54153890455e+18,27131715,https://scontent.cdninstagram.com/t51.2885-15/e35/19227888_434457730286781_8956364636005859328_n.jpg,"Courage doesn't mean you don't get afraid. Courage means you don't let fear stop you.
•
•
•
•
•
•
•
•
•
#vancouver #bcplace #beautifulday #beautifulbc #explorebc #clouds #sky #city #cityliving #eveningsky #seaside #adventure #bc #instagood #goodvibes #goodtimes #positivevibes #instadaily #instagram #picoftheday #instagold #pictureoftheday #igdaily",5,0,1497985779,BVkpXddDAEC,741066469,Yaletown,yaletown,NA,,49.2757019,-123.1199065
```

Comment: Hi @monotonic!  Could you please share an example line from `inst.csv`?  Thanks

Comment: sure, it's included now

Comment: That's not a `csv` at all .... I can't imagine how you'd possibly expect Pandas to know how to read that.  Do you know how to format a `csv`?

Comment: eg, `unnamed,X, unnamed,id,user_id,post_src,caption,likes,comments,date,code,location_id,location_name,location_slug,location_type,postal_code,lat,lng` and then on the next line `4,3,3,1.541539e+18,27131715,"https://scontent.cdninstagram.com/t51.2885-15/"," etc etc.  would be a valid `csv` format.  Your data isn't `csv` format at all, therefore `pd.read_csv` can't read it.

Comment: This is not the point. This is the result of `df.head()`

Comment: Ok well can you share a valid `csv` line?  I (and others) are more likely to be able to debug your problem if we have a line of sample data to run through your code and debug with.

Comment: it's included now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're getting nothing back because you don't have any entries between those timestamps.  Here's an example, with your data:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('inst.csv',encoding='utf-8')
df.date = pd.to_datetime(df.date)
df.set_index(pd.DatetimeIndex(df.date),inplace=True)
more = df.between_time('0:00','9:00')
less = df.between_time('11:00','12:00')
print(more)
```

I get back:

```
                                Unnamed: 0  X  Unnamed..0            id  \
date
1970-01-01 00:00:01.497985779           4  3           3  1.541539e+18

                               owner_id  \
date
1970-01-01 00:00:01.497985779  27131715

                                                                        post_src  \
date
1970-01-01 00:00:01.497985779  https://scontent.cdninstagram.com/t51.2885-15/...

                                                                         caption  \
date
1970-01-01 00:00:01.497985779  Courage doesn't mean you don't get afraid. Cou...

                               likes  comments                          date  \
date
1970-01-01 00:00:01.497985779      5         0 1970-01-01 00:00:01.497985779

                                      code  location_id location_name  \
date
1970-01-01 00:00:01.497985779  BVkpXddDAEC    741066469      Yaletown

                              location_slug  location_type  postal_code  \
date
1970-01-01 00:00:01.497985779      yaletown            NaN          NaN

                                     lat         lng
date
1970-01-01 00:00:01.497985779  49.275702 -123.119906
```

Then if I print `less`:

```
Empty DataFrame
Columns: [Unnamed: 0, X, Unnamed..0, id, owner_id, post_src, caption, likes, comments, date, code, location_id, location_name, location_slug, location_type, postal_code, lat, lng]
Index: []
```

Here's my `inst.csv`, based off your example data:

```
,X,Unnamed..0,id,owner_id,post_src,caption,likes,comments,date,code,location_id,location_name,location_slug,location_type,postal_code,lat,lng 4,3,3,1.54153890455e+18,27131715,https://scontent.cdninstagram.com/t51.2885-15/e35/19227888_434457730286781_8956364636005859328_n.jpg,"Courage doesn't mean you don't get afraid. Courage means you don't let fear stop you. • • • • • • • • •
#vancouver #bcplace #beautifulday #beautifulbc #explorebc #clouds #sky #city #cityliving #eveningsky #seaside #adventure #bc #instagood #goodvibes #goodtimes #positivevibes #instadaily #instagram #picoftheday #instagold #pictureoftheday #igdaily",5,0,1497985779,BVkpXddDAEC,741066469,Yaletown,yaletown,NA,,49.2757019,-123.1199065
```

If you want to be more explicit with your time strings, write 'AM' or 'PM', like this:

```
anotherWay = df.between_time('6:00PM','1:00AM')
```

Comment: If you make a `.csv` file exactly like the one in my answer, and then run the code in my answer, do you get the same results I do?

Comment: @monotonic if you figured out the answer to your problem you should write your own answer accordingly and accept it.

Answer (score 1):

`df.date = pd.to_datetime(df.date,unit='s')` unit is by default nanosecond